# How do I use a PerspectiveCamera with a Stage and Viewport

Tags: android, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I am trying to write a game using Scene2d Stages and Box2d. When I test my setup with an Orthographic camera it displays everything as expected, but when I switch to a Perspective camera I always end up with a blank black screen.

I tested a Perspective camera without a Stage and Viewport and I was able to position the camera and draw on screen as expected.

What else do I need to do to make PerspectiveCamera work with ExtendViewport (and to have it look at the same thing the Ortho camera does)?

I've also tried changing the z-axis position of the camera without any results

```
MyClass extends Stage {

     MyClass() {
        super(createViewport());
        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
     }

     private static Viewport createViewport() {
         PerspectiveCamera cam = new PerspectiveCamera();
         cam.fieldOfView = 67f;

         //OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera();

         //Results in [100.0 x 166.1111] on Pixel-2 Portrait
         return new ExtendViewport(C.MIN_WORLD_WIDTH, C.MIN_WORLD_HEIGHT,
                            C.MIN_WORLD_WIDTH, 2f * C.MIN_WORLD_WIDTH, cam);
     }

}
```

Here's the view with an Othographic camera:

[image: demo]

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: No, I didn't :/